# Behavior of val() for multiple select in jQuery changed?

Tags: jquery, select

So everywhere I looked everybody says that to output values of selected options in a multiple select element one should use something like the following `$('#selid :selected').val()` and that in such case val() will return an array of values. Well, I can't replicate this behaviour. As far as I can tell such code returns just the first selected value. [Here's a quick jsfiddle snippet that demonstrates that](http://jsfiddle.net/2late2die/AAegR/).

Notice that using each to iterate through `$('#selid :selected')` does work, but calling val() on that array does not produce an array of values as far as I can tell. In fact, calling `$('#selid :selected').val().each(...` results in an error message.

So, am I doing something wrong or has this behavior been changed at some point?

Comment: your JSfiddle works for me... if I select items 2 and 3 and click the button, `23` appears in the box below.

Comment: @Tomalak `$('#selid :selected').val()` returns a string, not an array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, your second comment is a lot more useful than the first one. Thanks for sharing your second thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "in such case val() will return an array of values. Well, I can't replicate this behaviour."

You never need to use `:selected` to get the value of a `<select>`. This is sufficient:

```
$('#selid').val()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WZRmD/

Comment: @Tomalak: um, yup. See the demo.

Comment: @Fosco @Tomalak: _"in such case val() will return an array of values. Well, I can't replicate this behaviour."_ The OP is trying to figure out how to get an array of the values.

Comment: @Fosco: It does? Looks like an array to me.

Comment: @Tomalak ah yes... in the console it is clearly an array, in the OP's fiddle when it was placed as the content of the div it appeared to be a string.

Comment: @Fosco it **is** a string in the OP's fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The `val` function gets the value of the *first* element in the set of matched elements. To get the value of multiple selected items, when using the `:selected` selector, you need to loop through the set, as you mention in your question.

For more information, read the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for `val()`.

Comment: I've added some clarification - you need to loop through the set of matched elements when using the `:selected` selector.

Comment: Actually I don't see that the jQuery docs make that distinction between val() and :selected).val(). As far as I can tell they're basically saying that $('select.foo option:selected').val(); and $('select.foo').val(); are equivalent, yet clearly that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @ilia I agree that the jQuery API docs are a bit misleading in the recommendation to use `:selected`. As I said in my answer, in practice you can pretty much always call `.val()` right on the `<select>` itself and you'll get back what you'd expect.