# Why do I get one int[] element that is 0 in controller and null is sent from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When a form contains no selected items, it creates me a table with one ite that is 0, how to remove it elegantly? where?

JS :

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function () {
                showLoader();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("Search", "Home")",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { secteurs: $("#secteursDiffusion").val(), auditeurs: $("#auditeursDiffusion").val(), audites: $("#auditesDiffusion").val(), services: $("#servicesDiffusion").val() },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#resultPlaceholder").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
```

At this point, when I evaluate in console $("#secteursDiffusion").val() for instance, I can see items that were selected in $("#secteursDiffusion"), OK (result:["676"]) ! And when I evaluate $("#auditesDiffusion").val() in console, this is null (result:null), so all is OK.

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(int[] secteurs, int[] auditeurs, int[] audites, int[] services)
        {   ...   }
```

when I breakpoint in the controller, I received audites (that were evaluated in console as null) with one item that is 0, why? And how remve it elegantly?

[image]

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

HTML Code of one input:

```
<select data-placeholder="Ajoutez un ou plusieurs secteurs" id="secteursDiffusion" multiple="multiple" name="secteursDiffusion">
<option value="992379">item55</option>
<option value="993147">item56</option>
<option value="996096">item57</option>
<option value="33033095">item58</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT2: with int?[]**
Same problem:
[image]

Comment: Why are your parameters `int[]`? your ajax call is using `.val()` of an element which is a single value.

Comment: instead of `int[] audites` it should be `int? audites` or `string audites` in controller action..

Comment: .val work with multiple values too @StephenMuecke, I receive multiple val in array in the controller like that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359565/behavior-of-val-for-multiple-select-in-jquery-changed

Comment: @Kartikeya : I can receive multiple values on each item, those are ListBox and the user can select multiple items by listbox

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I edited the first comment, do you want that I test without the JS library (chosen) that render the HTML for one field? mabye this is error because of the chose JS library? What do you think?

Comment: Wont make any difference. I see that your elements are multi-selects. Its a function of the `DefaultModelBinder` which initializes the arrays in the controller. You could use `int?[] secteurs` (nullable) which would mean it would still have one element but at least it would be `null`, not `0`. I'll explore the source code to see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the value is `null` you are still passing *some* value for `audites`. As it is not an array, MVC thinks you are passing an `int` value and so sets it to its default value - `0` (as Stephen pointed out, this is the behaviour of the `DefaultModelBinder`).

You need to ensure an array is passed, so if it is `null`, send `[]` instead - note that `audites` then becomes `null` in the controller action, rather than an empty array, but that makes more sense than `[0]`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function () {
    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Search", "Home")",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            secteurs: $("#secteursDiffusion").val() || [],
            auditeurs: $("#auditeursDiffusion").val() || [],
            audites: $("#auditesDiffusion").val() || [],
            services: $("#servicesDiffusion").val() || []
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#resultPlaceholder").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: perfect, understood and fixes! what else? :-)